Dell Monitor U2711 will not display at 2560x1440 resolution on Windows 11
I have a Dell display monitor U2711 and recently upgraded my Dell XPS desktop from Windows 7 to Windows 11. Under Windows 7 the monitor runs fine at 2560 * 1440 resolution and I can run the Display manager to change the screen layout without any problems. Under Windows 11 the resolution (default is 1024 * 768) and only the generic Windows driver is shown. The display manager will not run under Windows 11.
I checked the Dell website and they basically offer no resolution (a dedicated driver for Windows 11 is not forthcoming). I followed the steps they advised to check (Settings - System - Display Resolution - and then I find there is no option to set the monitor to its max resolution). I downloaded the driver from the Dell website for Windows 7 / 8 and installed it under Windows 11. Then tried to run this program. It recognises the display, but I cannot select any of the options presented. So I am stuck. Gone back to Windows 7.
Anyone has any suggestions?

Your hardware doesn't support Windows 11, specifically, your video card, though I'd guess other components are not supported either. What modifications did you have to run to get Windows 11 running?

If you want to use a modern OS, and the PC does not fully support Win 11, try Linux, which should have drivers. You can test that without need to install it by booting from a live USB, such as Ubuntu Live, https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started. If it works with the monitor and you like it, then install it.

There are a multitude of variations with regards to XPS, you need to tell us what graphic chip you are actually using. One possibility is that Dell may no longer support that unit, but perhaps NVidia & AMD still support the discreet gpu.

Good point regarding the graphics cards. I have two GEForce 8800 cards in the system each with 4GB of memory. The driver version is 311.06. I will check for an updated driver. Luckily I made an ISO image of Windows 11, so re- installing is not that bad.

For the GeForce 8800 cards, the latest OS that NVidia will support is Windows 10 with driver version 341.92.

More Information, I downloaded an updated driver for the graphics card and installed the new driver. Works a charm on Windows 7. Decided to reinstall Windows 11. The same problem. I found in the Advanced Display Settings details an error message that the device DISPLAY\DEFAULTMONITOR... could not be migrated. Checking the error log (Kernel PnP for Generic Device Driver gave error with event id 441. Checking the status of the NVIDIA Control Panel showed that the program is disabled. I think I may need to contact Microsoft to find out what is going on. Ah well back to Windows 7.
